# How to get the Multiple selected HTML elements from the ContentEditable div in Javascript

Tags: reactjs, arrays, next.js

I have been creating a rich text editor in React like CKeditor. I've almost got everything,my only concern is If the user selects the multiple text means I need to get the HTML that are selected. How can I achieve that?

Need to get all the HTML that are selected in the ContentEditable div using Range

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `window.getSelection()` method in combination with the `Range.cloneContents()` method to achieve this.

When a user selects text within your contentEditable div, you can call `window.getSelection()` to get a Selection object representing the range of text currently selected by the user.

Then, you can call `getRangeAt(0)` on the Selection object to get a Range object.

Finally, call `cloneContents()` on the Range object. This will return a DocumentFragment containing the selected content. You can then use outerHTML to get the HTML.

You can then call this function in your event handler for the user selection event.

This function also deals with the case where the browser doesn't support window.getSelection, which is unlikely these days but still good to have for robustness.

```
function getSelectedHtml() {
    let html = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection !== "undefined") {
        const sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            const container = document.createElement("div");
            for (let i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
            }
            html = container.innerHTML;
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection !== "undefined") {
        if (document.selection.type === "Text") {
            html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
        }
    }
    return html;
}
```

Comment: This is working thanks, How can I loop through the elements and use the "replaceWith()" with new elements...

Comment: const userSelection = window.getSelection();
const selectedTextRange = userSelection.getRangeAt(0);
const clonedContentsList = selectedTextRange.cloneContents();
for (let i = 0; i < clonedContentsList.childNodes.length; i++) {
            const prevchildNode = clonedContentsList.childNodes[i];
            const newElement2 = document.createElement(elementName);
            newElement2.classList.add(className);
            newElement2.innerHTML= prevchildNode.innerHTML;
            prevchildNode.replaceWith(newElement2);
          }
This How I tried but not working